# Derive HTML based on value of nested array

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

Looking to group and create relevant html based from an object.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const items = [
  {
    value: 'fruit',
    label: 'apple',
  },
  {
    value: 'Mango',
    label: 'Mango',
    groupBy: 'fruit'
  },
  {
    value: 'Orange',
    label: 'Orange',
    groupBy: 'fruit'
  },
  // Will need to group all above by fruit, similarly
  {
    value: 'vegetable',
    label: 'artichoke',
  },
  {
    value: 'aubergine',
    label: 'aubergine',
    groupBy: 'vegetable'
  }

];

  _renderItems = () => {

    const itemsList = _.chain(items)
    .map(item => (
      this._renderItem(item)
    ))
    .value()

    return '<div class="item-container">'+ itemsList+'</div>'

  }
  _renderItem = (item = {}) => {
    console.log(item)
  }

   _renderItems()

/*
desired output
<div class="fruit">
Label:Apple
Label:Mango
Label:Orange
</div>
<div class="vegetable">
label:artichoke
label:aubergine
label:broccoli
</div>
 */
```

**Code sample here of progress here https://repl.it/repls/ElectronicUsableTheories** . In general, I have trouble adding a wrapping div based on grouped value.

So all fruit should be grouped first key will not have groupBy key but its value will be the key of all next items which needs to be grouped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the items by the `groupBy` or by `value` if `groupBy` doesn't exist. Then you can map the groups. The 2nd parameter that map passes to the callback is the key (the `groupBy` value), that you can use as the class. It addition map the items, take the `label`, and format. Combine the group's string, and the `itemList`'s string, and return.

```js
const items = [{"value":"fruit","label":"apple"},{"value":"Mango","label":"Mango","groupBy":"fruit"},{"value":"Orange","label":"Orange","groupBy":"fruit"},{"value":"vegetable","label":"artichoke"},{"value":"aubergine","label":"aubergine","groupBy":"vegetable"}];

const _renderItem = ({ label } = {}) => `label: ${label}\n`;

const _renderItems = () =>
  _(items)
  .groupBy(o => o.groupBy || o.value) // if not groupBy use value
  .map((group, key) => {
    const itemsList = group.map(_renderItem).join('');

    return `<div class="item-container ${key}">\n${itemsList}</div>`;
  })
  .join('\n');

const result = _renderItems();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have mutated the array first item doesn't have groupBy Key

Comment: I thought it was an oversight. What should the 1st item be grouped by?

Comment: First item is category itself i. e. first item value is category for next 3 child objects. Similarly when groupBy is not found in object value is the groupBy field. To answer first item groupBy is the value of key "value"

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle the items without the `groupBy` property.